# What is Protocol Oriented Programming in Swift? What added value does it bring?

Tags: objective-c, oop, swift2, protocols, delegation

From Apple's own website: "At the heart of Swift's design are two incredibly powerful ideas: **protocol-oriented programming** and first class value semantics."

Can someone please elaborate what exactly is protocol oriented programming, and what added value does it bring?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943209/is-there-a-difference-between-swift-2-0-protocol-extensions-and-java-c-abstract?rq=1) and watched the Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/), but coming from an Objective-C background still haven't understood it. I kindly ask for a *very* plain English answer along with code snippets & technical details about how it's different from Objective-C.

Just *one* of the confusions I have is using `<tableViewDelegate, CustomDelegate>` Couldn't we also conform to multiple protocols in Objective-C as well? So again how is Swift new?

---

EDIT: See [Protocol-Oriented Views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AySlYrel7fc&t) video. I find this video to be more basic and easier to grasp a meaningful use case. The WWDC video itself is a bit advanced and requires more breadth. Additionally the answers here are somewhat abstract.

Comment: It is (almost) the same as [interfaced based programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface-based_programming) in, say, Java.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis But I don't know Java! Would I still understand it easily?

Comment: Watch [Crusty](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/)

Comment: @vadian That's the exact same video he referenced in his question. But, that video is such an accessible introduction to the topic that I'm unclear how you can watch it and and have these sorts of questions.

Comment: @Rob I'll watch again...my major confusion is about the different meanings 'protocol' carries in the 2 languages and we already have some form of multiple protocol conformance in objc

Comment: @asma22 There is no difference in the meaning of "protocol". Swift just added new features to protocols (protocol extensions, protocol generics, etc.), but it's fundamentally still the same meaning of "protocol" as in ObjC.

Comment: IMO this question and the answers are pretty useful.  It's a shame when great questions get closed because they are deemed not to be a good fit for SO.

Comment: The video makes me sad at 8:50 when Professor Blowing Your Mind basically states that OOP is single inheritance.  His arguments may be solid for single inheritance, but are much less compelling in the universe where OOP means more than one superclass.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Preface: POP and OOP are not mutually exclusive. They're design paradigms that are greatly related.

The primary aspect of POP over OOP is that is prefers [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). There are several benefits to this.

In large inheritance hierarchies, the ancestor classes *tend* to contain most of the (generalized) functionality, with the leaf subclasses making only minimal contributions. The issue here is that the ancestor classes end up doing a lot of things. For example, a `Car` drives, stores cargo, seats passengers, plays music, etc. These are many functionalities that are each quite distinct, but they all get indivisibly lumped into the `Car` class. Descendants of `Car`, such as `Ferrari`, `Toyota`, `BMW`, etc. all make minimal modifications to this base class.

The consequence of this is that there is reduced code reuse. My `BoomBox` also plays music, but it's not a car. Inheriting the music-playing functionality from `Car` isn't possible.

What Swift encourages instead is that these large monolithic classes be broken down into a composition of smaller components. These components can then be more easily reused. Both `Car` and `BoomBox` can use `MusicPlayer`.

Swift offers multiple features to achieve this, but the most important by far are protocol extensions. They allow implementation of a protocol to exist separate of its implementing class, so that many classes may simply implement this protocol and instantly gain its functionality.

Comment: 1: In objc...every protocol is to be applied onto its delegate. Like you say this protocol's name is <tableviewdelegate>

Comment: The naming has simply changed for some core types. The Foundation Frameworks's (`NS*` / `UI*`) protocols tend to keep their naming as it used to be. The delegate pattern still exists.

Comment: Isn't composition only a matter of how you write your code? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192203/objective-c-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @asma22 "only a matter of how you write your code" Yeah, so? OOP is just "a matter a how you write your code". As is POP.

Comment: My point is, if it's something that could have already been done in Objective-C before, then what's all the fuss about it in Swift? Meaning your answer doesn't really highlight the *differences* as per the link above. Kindly, can you explain the extensions part and what you mean by default implementation. Please explain in Plain English as much as possible

Comment: @asma22 just because it was possible, doesn't mean it was the prevailing convention. The designers of Swift used the opportunity of developing a new language to rethink the kinds of design patterns they want to embrace. For more on protocol extensions read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521

Comment: I suggest you give a read through the entire language guide. It's very well written and will answer many of these sorts of questions far better than I could

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Fair enough I will,  ASAIK I messed up to design patterns: Delegation pattern and Adapter pattern since both were using `protocol`s to do their work and I was mostly using the delegation side of it in tableViews, CollectionViews, etc. Please correct me if I am wrong about adapter vs. delegation. **P.S.** I am not saying this a beautiful question, but this is a question that when I ask my peers on the *same level*, we all get confused and not that it counts but 3 people favorited it :]

Comment: 1) I removed the itemized questions so kindly if you can update accordingly. 2) I would appreciate if you can add some laymen explanation for defaulting and its technical benefits as you have done for 'composition over inheritance' . Or possibly something I haven't mentioned...

Comment: @Honey `I would appreciate if you can add some laymen explanation for defaulting and its technical benefits` Of POP over OOP? Inheritance is the defining trait of OOP. POP avoids this, and uses POP instead. There's not much more to it.

Comment: @Alexander I'd argue that the framing of OOP above is focused  on single inheritance.  With multiple inheritance, mixins and functionalities can be very small and lead to comfortably sized testable leaf subclasses without the imposition of always implementing full interfaces.  It seems like POP and OOP from this perspective can go hand in hand smoothly.

Comment: @iJames This is true, but multiple inheritance is quite rare. C++ is the only big player in this space. Python technically has multiple inheritance, but it's usually avoided

Comment: @Alexander Python is avoided or multiple inheritance is avoided?  :-)  I suppose if we're going to say OOP is generally single inheritance, we need to reclassify multiple inheritance languages in a new category.  I don't have the personal experience developing fully tested multiple inheritance to say it's a fine alternative, but at face value, it knocks down the main argument of against single inheritance, the problem of massive base classes.  So it's important to be clear that (MIB)OOP hasn't been shot down as severely (though it still could be if somebody wanted to try.)

Answer (score 20):

**It surprised me that none of the answers mentioned value type in POP.**

To understand what is protocol oriented programming, you need to understand what are drawbacks of objected oriented programming.

1. It (Objc) has only one inheritance. If we have very complicated hierarchy of inheritance, the bottom class may have a lot of unnecessary state to hold.
2. It uses class which is a reference type. Reference type may cause code unsafe. e.g. Processing collection of reference types while they are being modified.

While in protocol oriented programming in swift:

1. It can conform **multiple** protocols.
2. It can be used by not only class, but also **structures** and **enumerations**.
3. It has protocol extension which gives us **common functionality** to all types that conforms to a protocol.
4. It prefers to use **value type** instead of reference type. Have a look at the standard swift library [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift), you can find majority of types are structures which is value type. But this doesn't mean you don't use class at all, in some situation, you have to use class.

So protocol oriented programming is nothing but just an another programming paradigm that try to solve the OOP drawbacks.

Comment: 1. OOP can be done with multiple inheritance, as C++ does, 2. Structures exist to facilitate POP, so their lack of OOP isn't relevant. Enums could be implemented by classes too. 3. Protocol extensions / mixins are possible in OOP.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov 1. Yes, agree, but some popular language cannot have multiple inheritance like c#, Java etc. It is Apple thing so I mainly differ it from Objc 2. From the video of Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift, it clearly demonstrates why Apple prefer type value not reference value. So Structure or Enums conform protocol is reasonable and many language cannot do that. 3. Protocol extension is not just extension but you can also give a default implementation of method without using inheritance to reduce the duplicated code. Let me know if I am not correct.

Answer (score 11):

In Objective C protocol is the same thing as interface in most languages. So in Objective C protocol's usage is limited to [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principle "*Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.*"

In Swift protocols were improved so seriously that since they still could be used as interfaces in fact they are closer to classes (like [Abstract classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) in C++)

In Objective C the only way to share functionality between classes is an inheritance. And you could inherit the only **one** parent class. In Swift you could also adopt **as many protocols as you want**. And since protocols in Swift can have default methods implementation they give us a fully-functional [Multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). More flexibility, better code reuse - awesome!

**Conclusion:**

**Protocol Oriented Programming** is mostly the same as **OOP** but it pays additional attention to functionality sharing not only via inheritance but also via protocol adoption ([Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)).

Worth to mention that in C++ abstract classes are very similar to protocols in Swift but no one says C++ supports some specific type of OOP. So in *general* POP is a one of the versions of OOP if we speak about programming paradigms. For Swift POP is an improved version of OOP.

Comment: I understand some parts of what you are saying. And thanks for the wikipedia link. It's great. So you are saying the word protocol doesn't have similar meaning in the 2 languages? For Objective-C isn't that we can also make our viewcontroller class conform to multiple protocols? Extending its functionality? I don't understand the difference. Kindly can you elaborate more

Comment: I think you have got the main idea. In Objective C protocol is the same thing as `interface` in most languages. In Swift protocols were improved so seriously that since they still could be used as interfaces in fact they are closer to classes (like `Abstract classes` in C++).

Comment: Can you please vote for re-opening the question? I believe the ambiguity is removed now

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the above answer

**Protocol** is a interface in which signature of methods and properties are declared and any class/struct/enum subclassing the enum must have to obey the contract means they have to implement all the methods and properties declared in superclass protocol.

**Reason to use Protocol**

Classes provide single inheritance and struct doesn't support inheritance. Thus protocols was introduced.

**Extension** The methods declare inside the protocol can be implemented inside the extension to avoid the redundancy of the code in case protocol is being inherited in multiple class / struct having same method implementation. We can call the method by simply declaring the object of struct/enums. Even we can restrict the extension to a list of classes, only restricted class will be able to use the method implemented inside the extension while rest of the classes have to implement method inside own class.

**Example**

```
protocol validator{

    var id : String{ get }
    func capitialise()-> (String)

}

extension validator where Self : test{
    func capitialise() -> String{
        return id.capitalized
    }
}

class test : validator {

    var id: String

    init(name:String) {
        id = name
    }
}

let t = test(name: "Ankit")
t.capitialise()
```

**When to use** In OOP suppose we have a vehicle base class which is inherited by the airplane, bike, car etc. Here break, acceleration may be common method among three subclass but not the flyable method of airplane. Thus if we are declaring flyable method also in OOP, the bike and car subclass also have the inherit flyable method which is of no use for those class.  Thus in the POP we can declare two protocols one is for flyable objects and other is for break and acceleration methods. And flyable protocol can be restricted to use by only the airplane

Answer (score 1):

**Protocol Oriented Programming(POP)**

protocol-first approach

- Protocol as a key point of OOP concept. abstraction, inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation.
- Protocol as a base for SOLID[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087638/4770877)
- Protocol instead of class hierarchy tree. Its is hard to support class inheritance. Moreover it has some performance impact
- Class/struct can implements **multiple** protocols(a kind of multiple inheritance)
- Composition over inheritance.

```
extension MyClass: MyProtocol {
}
```

- Default method. Shared implementation for all implementators

```
extension MyProtocol {
    func foo() {
        //logic
    }
}
```

- Protocol inheritance. One protocol can extends another protocol. Implementator of protocol one should implements all from first and the second protocols

```
protocol ProtocolB: ProtocolA {
}
```

- value type implement protocol(as usual reference type)[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219141/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

what is protocol oriented programming? What’s POP?

- is a new programming paradigm

- we start designing our system by defining protocols. We rely on new concepts: protocol extensions, protocol inheritance, and protocol compositions.
- value types can inherit from protocols, even multiple protocols. Thus, with POP, value types have become first class citizens in Swift. value types like enums, structs
  *POP lets you to add abilities to a class or struct or enum with protocols which supports multiple implementations.
- Apple tells us:
  “Don’t start with a class, start with a protocol.”
  Why? Protocols serve as better abstractions than classes.

**Protocols**: are a fundamental feature of Swift. They play a leading role in the structure of the Swift standard library and are a common method of abstraction.
Protocols are used to define a “blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality.”

Benefits of Protocol-Oriented Programming:

- All classes are decoupled from each other
- Separating the concerns of declaration from implementation
- Reusability
- Testability

Comment: This answer would benefit a lot from examples. In its current form, it's a bit abstract...

Answer (score 0):

Protocol Oriented Programming (POP)

- Came since Swift 2.0
- class (OOP)

  - is reference type
  - memory leak, incorrect data stored,race condition to access in complex multi-thread environments
  - can be large by inheriting members of super classes at chain time
- struct (POP)

  - is value type  -    each time a fresh copy is made when needed
  - provides multi inheritance  -   inherits protocols
  - Protocol :
  - Defines what Methods, Properties and Initializes are required o Can
    inherit another Protocol(s)
  - Don’t have to use override keyword to implement protocol functions
- Extensions:

  - Default value and
    The default implementation for protocol
  - Can add extra members to
    protocol