# What is the difference between a Protocol method in Swift and an abstract method in Java?

Tags: java, swift, protocols, abstract

I'm new to Java and I'm currently learning about abstract methods and they sound exactly like `Protocol` methods in Swift. They are both methods that must be implemented and cannot have a default implementation.

However, when I Google, "Are Java abstract methods the same as Swift Protocol methods," all of the answers basically say that Swift doesn't offer abstract methods.

So my questions are:

1. Am I right to assume that an abstract method is at least *similar* to a protocol method?
2. What is the **key difference** between the two?

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859334/compare-protocol-in-swift-vs-interface-in-java ?

Comment: Don't know why that comment is getting so many upvotes. An interface can declare methods with a default implementation which is a key feature that `Procotol`s cannot do.

Comment: @MartinR I believe OP is talking about `abstract` methods rather than `interface`s. Swift doesn't have a direct equivalent for `abstract` classes/methods.

Comment: @Ryan Protocol requirements *can* have default implementations by way of protocol extensions.

Comment: I just assumed the same could be done with Java but can you explain what makes them different besides that?

Comment: I added the link *assuming* that it might be helpful to OP, not as a possible duplicate. I apologize if that was misleading.

Comment: Also, that question says that `interface`s are similar to `Protocol`s where questions about `abstract` methods and Swift get answers like yours, that their is not a Swift equivalent.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943209/is-there-a-difference-between-swift-2-0-protocol-extensions-and-java-c-abstract.

Comment: @MartinR thank you. The second link does make this question a duplicate.